# EF 6.1.3 and Fake DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, unit-testing, dbcontext

I want to create in-memory fake DbContext with stable data, which it's easy to control and not requires real DB.
I have the following code for my Repository:

```
    public class EFEditorialRepository : PixlocateBusinessLogic.IEditorialRepository
    {
        private readonly PixlocateEntities _db;
        public EFEditorialRepository()
        {
            _db = new PixlocateEntities();
        }

        public EFEditorialRepository(PixlocateEntities db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        // my methods here
   }
```

where PixlocateEntities - automatically generated class by Entity Framework:

```
public partial class PixlocateEntities : DbContext
{
    public PixlocateEntities()
        : base("name=PixlocateEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
```

then I implement fake Db Context:

```
public class FakePixlocateEntities : PixlocateEntities
{
    public override DbSet<EditorialPixlocateRequest> EditorialPixlocateRequests
    {
        get
        {
            var r = new List<EditorialPixlocateRequest>();

            r.Add(
                    new PixlocateDB.EditorialPixlocateRequest() {
                        ID = 1,
                        Deadline = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1),
                        DateCreated = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2),
                        RequestTypeID = 1,
                        RequestUserID = 1,
                        SpecialInstructions = "Spec instructions",
                        RequestStatusID = 1,
                        SmartphonePhotographerResponses =
                        {
                            new PixlocateDB.SmartphonePhotographerResponse() { ID =1 , DateAdded = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-40), RequestID = 1, UserID = 2, ResponseText = "response" }
                        },
                        Address = "dfdfd",
                        AddressFound = true
                    });
            r.Add(
                    new PixlocateDB.EditorialPixlocateRequest()
                    {
                        ID = 2,
                        Deadline = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
                        DateCreated = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10),
                        RequestTypeID = 1,
                        RequestUserID = 1,
                        SpecialInstructions = "Spec instructions",
                        RequestStatusID = 1,
                        SmartphonePhotographerResponses =
                        {
                            new PixlocateDB.SmartphonePhotographerResponse() { ID =1 , DateAdded = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4), RequestID = 1, UserID = 2, ResponseText = "response" }
                        },
                        Address = "dfdfd",
                        AddressFound = true
                    });

            return r.AsQueryable();
        }

        set
        {
            base.EditorialPixlocateRequests = value;
        }
    }
}
```

problem is I can't fill DbSet objects. I get

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)    PixlocateDB C:\www\Pixlocate\PixlocateDB\FakePixlocateEntities.cs   52  Active

How to fill this context?

Comment: I created a wrapper for this based on info from Microsoft on [GitHub -DbContextMockForUnitTests](https://github.com/IgorWolbers/DbContextMockForUnitTests). Disclaimer, its my code but based on [Testing with your own test doubles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314431.aspx). Hopefully this will put you on the right path.

Comment: I have read that article. I want to do it without any mock objects

Comment: That is not possible. There is no in memory only implementation of EF that I am aware of (not taking into the account EF Core but you mention 6.1.3 in your post). You need to mock EF so the behavior is overriden and that the DbSets contain data that you want to test with. Without some type of mock / substitute framework you really won't get far. Out of curiosity, what is your reason to not want to use a mock framework?

Comment: @Igor Just wanted to understand how mock works :)

Comment: Most of these frameworks are open source, you can check them out yourself, build them, debug them, etc. Here are 2 popular ones (top of my head in no particular order). [NSubstitute](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute), [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4).